# Update multiple values to object list in c#

Tags: c#, list

How to update multiple property of object in list?

```
foreach(emp e in emps){
    list1.Where(x => x.ID == e.ID && x.Salary < 5000).FirstOrDefault().Level = B;
    list1.Where(x => x.ID == e.ID && x.Salary < 5000).FirstOrDefault().Hike = e.Hike;
    list1.Where(x => x.ID == e.ID && x.Salary < 5000).FirstOrDefault().Salary = (e.Hike + 100)*e.Salary/100 ;
}
```

I dont want to use multiple in-line query for each field. Also it should update same single object.
Note : e.ID is not unique key. list1 can contain duplicate Ids

Comment: `var bob = list.Where(x => x.ID == e.empID && x.Salary > 5000).FirstOrDefault();` Then set the properties like any other object.

Comment: If you'd like a more precise answer, please provide a [mcve] including sample inputs.

Comment: Your current code is inefficient because it's searching in the list for the same object three times.  Do what @mjwills suggests and pull the object once, then set its properties after.

Comment: `I dont want to use multiple in-line query for each field.` There is no nice easy way to do this, just as there is no nice easy way to set multiple properties of an (existing) object at once. `Also it should update same single object.` My suggestion will do that.

Comment: By sharing a [mcve] we can provide alternate options (e.g. using something other than a list) for you to consider.

Comment: @DragandDrop The OP wants to update only the first one - `Also it should update same single object`.

Comment: @mjwills - Instead of extracting single object then updating properties, is it possible to update item in same list1 ?

Comment: " is it possible to update item in same list1 " the item will be updated inside the list, because you extract only the reference to this item. Changes on the item will be also made to the entry in the list, because both reference to the same object

Answer (score 8):

You need to query your list only once

```
foreach (emp e in emps)
{
    var item = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == e.empID && x.Salary > 5000);
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.Level = B;
        item.Hike = e.Hike;
        item.Salary = (e.Hike + 100) * e.Salary / 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: .. and fixed the potential `NullReferenceException` at `.FirstOrDefault().Level = B;`

Answer (score 1):

After giving lots of try. Looks like these will work :

```
foreach(emp e in emps){
    int index = list1.FindIndex(x => x.ID == e.ID && x.Salary < 5000);
    if(index != -1)
    {
        list1[index].Level = 'B';
        list1[index].Hike = e.Hike;
        list1[index].Salary = (e.Hike + 100)*e.Salary/100;
    }
}
```

What you guys feel ?

Comment: That is just like my suggestion (and @fubo's answer), except slightly more complicated, verbose and slower. There is no point getting the index like that. To get the index you had to find the item - you may as well use the item instead!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Foo` with your class

```
foreach (emp e in emps)
{
    if (list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == e.empID && x.Salary > 5000) is Foo f)
    {
        f.Level = B;
        f.Hike = e.Hike;
        f.Salary = (e.Hike + 100) * e.Salary / 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference : [Is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) operator `expr is type varname`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a solution that updates the object in place, which I suspect the OP wants too.

```
int i = yourList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == "123" && x.Salary < 5000);

if (i > 0) { 
   yourList[i].Level = "foo";
   yourList[i].Hike = "bar";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No explicit search, no nested loops: (if ID is your primary Key)

```
 foreach(item in list.Join(emps, x=>x.ID, e=>e.empID, (l,e)=> (l,e)).Where(x => x.l.Salary > 5000))
 {
    item.l.Level = B;
    item.l.Hike = item.e.Hike;
    item.l.Salary = (item.e.Hike + 100) * item.e.Salary / 100;
}
```

Append .OfType() if you need to.